# How to combine List items

Tags: c#, linq, list

I've a class like this:

```
public class ReportList
    {
        public int? ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public int LevelId { get; set; }
        public int Minutes { get; set; }
        public int Hours { get; set; }
        public int ExtraMinutes { get; set; }
        public int ExtraHours { get; set; }
    }
```

And I've list of this class

```
List<ReportList> repList = new List<ReportList>();
```

I've added items to this list:

```
repList.Add(new ReportList(1 , "a" , "project a", 2, 30, 1, 45, 2));
repList.Add(new ReportList(1 , "b" , "project a", 2, 30, 2, 15, 1));
repList.Add(new ReportList(1 , "c" , "project a", 2, 0, 3, 10, 0));
```

I want to combine this list items into one item by sum minutes and hours. So the list should be like this:

```
{1, "a", "project a", 2, 60, 6, 70, 3};
```

What can I do?

Comment: What about the `"b"` and `"c"`? How do you decide which `Name` to use? And what have you already tried to solve this?

Comment: From System.Linq use GroupBy and then Sum on the group values.

Comment: @RenéVogt this is not a problem. It can be "abc"

Comment: @team16sah is it possible to have a feed back? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GroupBy` extension method on `ProjectId`,`ProjectName`  and `LevelId` fields.

```
var results = repList.GroupBy(x=> new {x.ProjectId, x.ProjectName, LevelId })
       .Select(x=> new  // or create new ReportList object.
        {
            ProjectId = x.Key.ProjectId,  
            ProjectName =  x.Key.ProjectName,
            Name = x.First().Name,   // I assume it is first one as per example, modify if you want.
            LevelId = x.Key.LevelId,
            Minutes =  x.Sum(s=>s.Minutes),
            Hours =  x.Sum(s=>s.Hours ),
            ExtraMinutes =  x.Sum(s=>s.ExtraMinutes ),               
            ExtraHours =  x.Sum(s=>s.ExtraHours)                                 
        })
       .ToList() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want more optimized version of answer posted by user *Hari Prasad* you could use following;

```
        int minuteSum = 0;
        int hoursSum = 0;
        int extraMinutesSum = 0;
        int extraHoursSum = 0;

        foreach (var report in repList)
        {
            minuteSum += report.Minutes;
            hoursSum += report.Hours;
            extraMinutesSum += report.ExtraMinutes;
            extraHoursSum += report.ExtraHours;
        }

        var firstItemInRepList = repList.First();
        var result = new ReportList(firstItemInRepList.ProjectId,
            firstItemInRepList.Name,
            firstItemInRepList.ProjectName,
            firstItemInRepList.LevelId,
            minuteSum,
            hoursSum,
            extraMinutesSum,
            extraHoursSum);
```

I know its more crude version but it will take less cpu.

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = repList
   .GroupBy(x => "all")
   .Select(x=> new {
        ProjectId = x.First().ProjectId,
        Name = x.First().Name,   
        ProjectName =  x.First().ProjectName,
        LevelId = x.First().LevelId,
        Minutes =  x.Sum(s=>s.Minutes),
        Hours =  x.Sum(s=>s.Hours ),
        ExtraMinutes =  x.Sum(s=>s.ExtraMinutes),
        ExtraHours = x.Sum(s=>s.ExtraHours)
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I am refering answer posted by user Hari Prasad, but as per question requirement we need to apply groupby only on ProjectId i guess.
Please refer below code.

```
var processedResult = repList.GroupBy(x => x.ProjectId)
        .Select(x => new ReportList
        {
            ProjectId = x.Key,
            ProjectName = x.First().ProjectName, //As per your example it is first row data
            Name = x.First().Name,   //As per your example it is first row data
            LevelId = x.First().LevelId,
            Minutes = x.Sum(s => s.Minutes),
            Hours = x.Sum(s => s.Hours),
            ExtraMinutes = x.Sum(s => s.ExtraMinutes),
            ExtraHours = x.Sum(s => s.ExtraHours)
        }).ToList();
```